# Using case statement in ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ) causes severe performance issues

Tags: sql-server, performance, dynamic, sql-order-by

Using case statement in `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY)` causes severe performance issues.

I have two queries the first one runs in 5 seconds, the second one takes a couple of minutes to run. I am trying to sort using a value passed to a stored procedure. Kindly let me know how I can fix this issue.

Query #1:

```
SELECT TOP (10)  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY POData.PurchaseOrderNumber) AS ROW_NUM,
    Received.QuantityReceived, POData.PurchaseOrderNumber,
    POData.*
FROM
    POData 
INNER JOIN 
    Received ON POData.Id = Received.PODataId
```

Query #2:

```
DECLARE @OrderBy nvarchar(32) = 'PurchaseOrderNumber'

SELECT TOP(10) 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                           CASE 
                              WHEN @OrderBy = 'PurchaseOrderNumber' 
                                 THEN POData.PurchaseOrderNumber 
                           END) AS ROW_NUM,
    Received.QuantityReceived, POData.*
FROM
    POData 
INNER JOIN 
    Received ON POData.Id = Received.PODataId
```

Comment: I assume you have an index on PurchaseOrderNumber. In the first case, the SQL engine can use this index, but in the second not. I don't know exactly your problem, but maybe creating different views (for every case) can help.

Comment: Be careful you don't waste efforts chasing ghosts caused by logical nonsense. First, the use of "top 10" without an order by clause simply limits the resultset to 10 row - ANY 10 rows. Next, your use of row_number serves no particular purpose in your query (though it might be useful for the consumer of the resultset). So - is this really a problem and, if so, in what context? Given the pseudo-dynamic nature of the query, what happens when `@OrderBy` contains a different value? My guess is that you should be using dynamic sql for this.

Comment: Suggest you read and consider the suggestions in this [kitchen sink discussion](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example). Not quite your situation but discusses issues related to this sort of "static optional" logic you use.